# Entity Framework, DBContext использует некорректный provider

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Есть проблема с созданием подключения, во время инициализации `DbContext` появляется ошибка
`Keyword not supported:'server'[System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnectionStringBuilder.GetIndex()]`.
Такое ощущение, что приложение использует провайдер `System.Data.SqlServerCe` вместо `System.Data.SqlClient`.
Я пытался по разному указывать строку подключение, добавил как в примере `DbProviderFactories` (может быть не правильно), но все равно получаю ту же самую ошибку.

Уточнение, это не совсем приложение, а плагин к приложению, поэтому я не могу задать строку подключения и провайдера в `config`, только в коде. На одном компьютере работает подключение к базе данных, а на другом нет. Видимо другой плагин настроил провайдера раньше. Поэтому искал еще как поменять провайдера или указать явно.

```
    public class DbSBMSContext: DbContext
    {

        public DbSBMSContext()
                    : base(GetConnection(), true)
        {

        }

        public static DbConnection GetConnection()
        {
            var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SqlClient");
            var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = @"Server=MDMSQL;" +
                                "initial catalog=SBMS;" +
                                "integrated security=True;" +
                                "MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" +
                                "App=EntityFramework;";
            return connection;
        }
    }
```

Comment: А если напрямую создавать `SqlConnection` без фабрики?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Почему то я сразу не догадался, что `SqlConnection` можно привести к  `DbConnection` . Это сработало, все супер!! Спасибо большое!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Большое спасибо @Alexander Petrov!
Проблема решилась с помощью создания `SqlConnection`.

```
private static string ConnectString = @"data source=MDMSQL;" +
                        "initial catalog=SBMS;" +
                        "integrated security=True;" +
                        "MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" +
                        "App=EntityFramework;"; 

public DbSBMSContext()
            : base(GetConnection(), true) {}

public static DbConnection GetConnection()
{
    DbConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectString);
    return dbConnection;
}
```